# iOS8 ASP.net callback event not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ios8, mobile-safari

The ASP.net button is not working on iOS8. The button tap happens but the click event is not firing.
**The same code works fine in other browsers - Chrome.** 
Never had this issue when on iOS7, even for Safari - issue has come up after **the update to iOS8**

Below is the code which i have in my aspx page :

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnLogin" Text="Next" OnClientClick="return fnValidateLoginData();"  />
```

Below is line which i have defined in the JS file for the validate function :

```
function ValidateImageCount()
{    
       var action_Nm =$("#ctl00_cphContent_hdn_action_Nm").val() ;        
       var transmittalKey = $("#ctl00_cphContent_hdn_transmittalKey").val() ;
       var cr_type = $("#ctl00_cphContent_hdn_cr_type").val() ; 
       var imageValues = $("#ctl00_cphContent_hdnImageValue").val();
       var webUserID =$("#ctl00_cphContent_hdnWebUserID").val() ; 
       var validateWebUser =$("#ctl00_cphContent_hdnValidateWebUser").val() ;
       var CR_ID = $("#ctl00_cphContent_hdn_cr_ID").val() ;

       var inputData ="{imageValues: \"" + imageValues + "\", webUserID:\""  + webUserID + "\",validateWebUser: \"" + validateWebUser + "\",action_Nm: \"" + action_Nm + "\", cr_type: \"" + cr_type + "\", transmittalKey: \"" + transmittalKey + "\", CR_ID: \"" + CR_ID + "\"}";





    fnCallServerMethod(inputData,""); 
   return false;  
}
```

Below is the callback event :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ac = new AuthenticationController();
            HttpContext hc = HttpContext.Current;
            #region ICallBack Reference

            // get reference of call back method named JSCallback 
            string cbref = Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this,
                            "arg", "fnGetOutputFromServer", "context");
            // Generate JS method trigger callback 
            string cbScr = string.Format("function fnCallServerMethod(arg," +
                                         " context) {{ {0}; }} ", cbref);
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),
                              "fnCallServerMethod", cbScr, true); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help: http://www.brillianceweb.com/blog/article/69/aspnet-20-misidentifies-safari-71-on-ios-and-os-x

We had a similar issue and it resolved ours.

Cheers!